# How do I use show and hide on multiple divs using an onclick button in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So for the past 2 days I have been trying to figure out how to get my code to show a question. After the submit button is pressed, I'd like to have the next question show and the previous question hide.

I am working on a game like Family Feud and would like each question to display at the top of the screen and not leave until after the submit button is pressed. I haven't written a function yet for submitting answers yet, as I just have been working on getting the questions to appear and disappear on click of the submit button. Here is a link to my code I have so far:

https://repl.it/E36p/0

I figured out how to have all the questions hide, while the first one is displayed and after the submit button is clicked, the 2nd question displays, but I can get the next question to display while the 2nd one hides. It winds up showing both question 2 and 3 instead.

I tried all kind of solutions from the toggle method, to setting up an array called questions to see if I could call do it that way and I can't hide them all when I used that either. Please help.

Thanks

Comment: Add your html and js here. The example also does not contain any buttons. Do you want buttons on each step with different text. Structure the html and it will be easier.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like you need to learn to use a debugger.  Please help yourself to some [complementary debugging techniques](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  If you still have issues afterwards, please feel free to come back with more details.

Comment: Sorry about that. Here is all of my code here under this link : https://repl.it/E37n/0    I have only one submit button and an input box for users to type their answers.

Answer (score 0):

1. Load your questions in json session wizard variable
2. Create method ej app.wizard.render(), in this method controle next question to display. You can create template (jsrender, dot.js) for wizard question and render next question.
3. Create method app.wizard.send(), in this method, send response, load response for active question and render next question.

for load questions, use jquery ajax to retreive questions in order and store in session.wizard.questions

next call app.wizard.render() and render first question without response

next on submit response user, send this response to server, load response en session.wizard.questions and call app.wizard.render().

I create basic sample for you:

`Code` [codepen](http://codepen.io/jl0nd0n0/pen/zoNgvg)

You need create ajax for retreive querys and send responses

Comment: Hello Jorge and thank you for your answer but I am confused. Are you telling me to create objects out of my questions and then create a method to control the next question. Also are you referring to another language because I don't have a server. I am trying to do this using front end languages HTML, CSS, and JavaScript with JQuery.

Comment: Okay, nice. Thanks so much Jorge.